# Why is the inverse power of a int numpy array 0 despite "from __future__ import division"?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, exponentiation

I always use `from __future__ import division` to avoid integer division problems. I just came across a case where it apparently still persists:

```
np.array([10])**(-1)
```

returns `array([0])`, contrary to `1/np.array([10])`, which returns `array([ 0.1])` as expected.

I know this can be fixed, e.g. by using `np.array([10])**(-1.)` or converting the array to floats using `astype('float')`. I would just like to know why it behaves like this, since it seems slightly inconsistent to me given that e.g. `10**(-1)` gives 0.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`numpy.array()` uses operator overloading to implement features. `**` is handled by the [`object.__pow__()` special method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__pow__), for example.

The `/` operator is normally handled by [`object.__div__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__div__) (and the `__rdiv__` method for right-hand-side values), and the `from __future__ import division` 'switch' causes Python to use the [`object.__truediv__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__truediv__) method instead.

However, the `**` operator is not influenced by the switch; Python will continue to call `object.__pow__` and `numpy` won't know you used the `__future__` import.

As such, it'll continue to return integer results when you give it integer operands; it will not coerce to `float` even then.

Note that Python offers a *floor division* operator too, in the form of the [`//` operator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) and the [`__floordiv__` hook](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__floordiv__). There is no such flooring equivalent for exponentiation, so `numpy` has no other options to offer you a distinction between using `float` and `int` operands.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Maybe the more confusing thing to me is then that 10**(-1) always seems to use float division, even without the "from future import division"

Comment: @jacob: see the [`**` power operator documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator); in Python using an integer exponent *used* to raise an exception instead. It was deemed more helpful to coerce to float instead in those cases. I guess that Numpy made a different choice here as their use-cases are different (different programmer audience).

Answer (score 2):

As a footnote to the answer given above, you can check what NumPy will return for particular input array types by inspecting the `types` attribute of the appropriate universal function.

For NumPy arrays, the power operator `**` corresponds to `np.power`:

```
>>> np.power.types
['bb->b', 'BB->B', 'hh->h', 'HH->H', 'ii->i', 'II->I', 'll->l', 'LL->L', 'qq->q', 
 'QQ->Q', 'ee->e', 'ff->f', 'dd->d', 'gg->g', 'FF->F', 'DD->D', 'GG->G', 'OO->O']
```

Python-compatible integer types are denoted by `l`, Python-compatible floats by `d` ([see here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html#arrays-scalars-character-codes)).

You can see that for two integer types, `**` will return another integer: `'ll->l'`

For NumPy arrays, the division operator `/` corresponds to `np.divide`:

```
>>> np.divide.types
['bb->d', 'BB->d', 'hh->d', 'HH->d', 'ii->d', 'II->d', 'll->d', 'LL->d', 'qq->d', 
 'QQ->d', 'ee->e', 'ff->f', 'dd->d', 'gg->g', 'FF->F', 'DD->D', 'GG->G', 'mq->m', 
 'md->m', 'mm->d', 'OO->O']
```

Here, given two integer types (and for most other inputs), a float will be returned: `'ll->d'`